# Windows form Vertical scrollbar is not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a panel and set Autoscroll property to true. i inserted few labels, textboxes, buttons and tablelayout panel inside the panel. If tablelayout have alot of rows then it hides the exceeding rows. Any help will be highly appreciated![image]

Comment: There might be a vertical scroll bar property as well you can set to Auto.

Comment: Any more information would be also appreciated - show your relevant source code for instance. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Using TableLayoutPanel to implement a grid control is never not a mistake.  Create a UserControl to represent a "row", use a FlowLayoutPanel to make it scrollable.  Or use a grid control.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure AutoSize is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure my AutoScrollMinSize has values set. Mine was 900, 600.